# Compilation error: `‘error_category’ does not name a type` with g++ 6.3.0

Tags: c++, c++11, cython

I try to compile this C++/Python library https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluidfft

If mpi4py is installed, it works well.

If mpi4py is not installed, code that does not use MPI cannot be compiled.

An error is raise during the compilation of a Cython file.  The error is long and it starts by:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from src_cpp/base/base_fft.h:10,
                 from fluidfft/fft2d/fft2d_with_fftw1d.cpp:543:
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:143:31: error: ‘error_category’ does not name a type
     error_code(int __v, const error_category& __cat) noexcept
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:152:27: error: ‘error_category’ does not name a type
     assign(int __v, const error_category& __cat) noexcept
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:172:11: error: ‘error_category’ does not name a type
     const error_category&
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/system_error:191:11: error: ‘error_category’ does not name a type
     const error_category*  _M_cat;

[...]
```

I guess it could be a C++11 problem (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_category) but I don't see how to solve the problem.

The compilation command is

```
g++ -pthread -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/home/users/me/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -I/home/users/me/opt/miniconda3/include -Isrc_cy -Ifluidfft/fft2d -Ifluidfft/fft3d -Isrc_cpp/base -Isrc_cpp/3d -Isrc_cpp/2d -Iinclude -I/home/users/me/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c fluidfft/fft2d/fft2d_with_fftw1d.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/fluidfft/fft2d/fft2d_with_fftw1d.o
```

## Edit Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Thanks to Ashwin Vishnu (see https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluidfft/issues/7/fluidfft-installation-fails-without-mpi4py), I can post a minimal example

```
/* test.cpp */
#include <Python.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cpu.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
  std::cout<<"Hello world";
  return 0;
}
```

compiled from fluidfft directory as follows:

```
g++ $(python-config --include) -Iinclude/ test.cpp
```

If we comment out cpu.h include, there are no errors.

The file cpu.h was taken from the pyfftw code: https://github.com/pyFFTW/pyFFTW/blob/master/include/cpu.h

Comment: @YSC: [C++14 is the default in GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html). Still, those errors clearly come from libstdc++ so something is very wrong with this installation.

Comment: Can you compile a simple [_Hello, World!_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a5b25db35f01758) program?

Comment: Yes I can compile the Hello world! program.

Comment: Can you reduce the failing code to a [mcve] and post that in your question?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46884363/1106415) (same error message, different scenario) - unfortunately, that one doesn't have an answer either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the package fluidfft's Cython source files relied on [a C++ header file `cpu.h`](https://bitbucket.org/fluiddyn/fluidfft/src/7dd6f55525ffa4cde8d04cc6a4b9b5f2ae4c1e59/include/cpu.h#lines-41:45) wherein the following preprocessor lines caused problems:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
  /* "inline" is a keyword */
#else
# define inline
#endif
```

My guess is the newer g++ compilers are strict on redefining reserved keywords. Following hints from an [essay on inline functions](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/inline.html), this block of code was replaced with:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
  /* "inline" is a keyword */
#else
# define INLINE
#endif

#ifndef INLINE
# if __GNUC__ && !__GNUC_STDC_INLINE__
#  define INLINE static inline
# else
#  define INLINE inline
# endif
#endif
```